# MS Access 2013, How to add totals row within SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm in need of some assistance. I have search and not found what I'm looking for. I have an assigment for school that requires me to use SQL. I have a query that pulls some colunms from two tables:

```
SELECT Course.CourseNo, Course.CrHrs, Sections.Yr, Sections.Term, Sections.Location
FROM Course 
INNER JOIN Sections ON Course.CourseNo = Sections.CourseNo
WHERE Sections.Term="spring";
```

I need to add a `Totals` row at the bottom to count the `CourseNo` and Sum the `CrHrs`. It has to be done through SQL query design as I need to paste the code. I know it can be done with the datasheet view but she will not accept that. Any advice?

Comment: which column(s) are you trying to total up? And what kind of "total" aggregation? (Sum, Count, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, you can union your query together with an aggregation query. Its not clear from your question which columns you are trying to get "Totals" from, but here's an example of what I mean using your query and getting counts of each (kind of useless example - but you should be able to apply to what you are doing):

```
SELECT
      [Course].[CourseNo]
    , [Course].[CrHrs]
    , [Sections].[Yr]
    , [Sections].[Term]
    , [Sections].[Location]
FROM
    [Course]
    INNER JOIN [Sections] ON [Course].[CourseNo] = [Sections].[CourseNo]
WHERE  [Sections].[Term] = [spring]
UNION ALL
SELECT
      "TOTALS"
    , SUM([Course].[CrHrs])
    , count([Sections].[Yr])
    , Count([Sections].[Term])
    , Count([Sections].[Location])
FROM
    [Course]
    INNER JOIN [Sections] ON [Course].[CourseNo] = [Sections].[CourseNo]
WHERE  [Sections].[Term] = “spring”
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Perfect look! It doesn't sum the CrHrs though, I tried adding the line in the second select statement but could not get it to work. Is it possible to sum that column while counting the others? Thank you for your reply!!

Comment: updated my answer to add the SUM with the CrHrs column. It should be able to sum that one and count the other columns, yes. If that is not working, are you getting an error, or is it just not returning the answer you expect?

Comment: That is perfect!! Thank you so much!!! I did have to encase the [spring] in quotes instead of brackets though. This was a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your "total" query separately, and then output both query results together with "UNION".
It might look like:

```
SELECT Course.CourseNo, Course.CrHrs, Sections.Yr, Sections.Term, Sections.Location
FROM Course 
INNER JOIN Sections ON Course.CourseNo = Sections.CourseNo
WHERE Sections.Term="spring"
UNION
SELECT "Total", SUM(Course.CrHrs), SUM(Sections.Yr), SUM(Sections.Term), SUM(Sections.Location)
FROM Course 
INNER JOIN Sections ON Course.CourseNo = Sections.CourseNo
WHERE Sections.Term="spring";
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this that says "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: That's highly possible because I didn't know your data types, so I put the "SUM" randomly. It should not be to too difficult to correct it I guess. However I agree with Lee Mac regarding the fact that it is a bad practice to mix data and aggregated data within the same query result.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can certainly `union` the aggregated totals query to the end of your original query, in my opinion this would be really bad practice and would be undesirable for any real-world application.

Consider that the resulting query could no longer be used for any meaningful analysis of the data: if displayed in a datagrid, the user would not be able to sort the data without the totals row being interspersed amongst the rest of the data; the user could no longer use the built-in `Totals` option to perform their own aggregate operation, and the insertion of a row only identifiable by the term `totals` could even conflict with other data within the set.

Instead, I would suggest displaying the totals within an entirely separate form control, using a separate query such as the following (based on your own example):

```
SELECT Count(Course.CourseNo) as Courses, Sum(Course.CrHrs) as Hours
FROM Course INNER JOIN Sections ON Course.CourseNo = Sections.CourseNo
WHERE Sections.Term = "spring";
```

However, since `CrHrs` are fields within your `Course` table and not within your `Sections` table, the above may yield multiples of the desired result, with the number of hours multiplied by the number of corresponding records in the `Sections` table.

If this is the case, the following may be more suitable:

```
SELECT Count(Course.CourseNo) as Courses, Sum(Course.CrHrs) as Hours
FROM 
    Course INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT s.CourseNo FROM Sections s WHERE s.Term = "spring") q
    ON Course.CourseNo = q.CourseNo
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I like this code you post, but she requires all data to be shown. I will use this in future projects though!